# Jquery UI Tabs reset content

Tags: jquery, windows, jquery-ui, tabs

I have three tabs set up in *Jquery UI*, each containing a single *Youtube* Embed.

Everything works fine, except that whenever I start one video in one tab and would like to switch to another tab, the preceding video doesn't stop automatically.

In other words, I need **JQUI** to stop all previous tabs content from playing as the user navigates to the next, otherwise overlapping (sound in this case) occurs.

Is that even possible? Any help is appreciated.

The html structure is as follows:

```
<div class="tabs">
    <div class="tabs-navi">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="spip.php?article1">Commercial</a></li>
            <li><a href="spip.php?article5">Fiction</a></li>
            <li><a href="spip.php?article4">Experimental</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--.tabs-navi-->
</div><!--#tabs-->
```

Comment: What do the embeds look like?

Comment: Hi Jon,

The website is: http://pierredesmaraismusik.com (the Video and Music sub-sections are the ones involved in my Q)

Comment: I updated the Q with the html structure. Each href is actually a single article containing an iframe like this one:

    <iframe width="820" height="461" src="http://www.youtube-nocookie.com/embed/videoseries?list=PLE14B1790A20F5FF5&hl=en_GB" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

Answer (score 0):

You could look at using popcorn.js and use the YouTube player to display the video through, it would then simply be a matter of hooking into the select event of the tab control and then call pause on the relevant popcorn player.

Answer (score 0):

The issues I've seen so far:

1. Because the page currently work as showing a video and hiding
   another 2, it's better to remove them or hide them from the DOM tree
2. Several div elements are using the same id attribute value, each id
   should be unique on the same page
3. There are some issues with the iframe video embedding code with
   Internet Explorer, the whole page would gone black sometimes...
   Firefox and Chrome don't have this issue, if you care about
   compatibility with IE, it would be better to stick with the old
   object embed method